# Anime/animated film(?) with two teens chased around an underground city by giant robots

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon, mecha

I saw this on TV once, in the 90's. I only remember vague details, such as a couple of teens being chased around an underground city by a pair of giant machines or robots (them being a pair I'm not so sure). The teens had a sort of vehicular robot/machine that had a single wheel.

If I'm not mistaken, the end scene showed one of the protagonists in a white void of sorts.

It had a dark theme to it, like in the scenes in the underground city, everything felt so ominous.

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MonowheelMayhem might have some references.

Comment: reminds me of this, probably not it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_b5Arzjjytw Mylène Farmer - Peut-être toi (Clip Officiel HD)

Answer (score 1):

The anime [Gurren Lagann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gurren_Lagann) features two teens being chased around an underground city by alien beast men driving giant robots, while riding their own smaller robot.  It differs from your description in that the teens' robot has legs, not wheels, and while they start off with just the two of them they quickly pick up more people as they get along.  They also make their way to the surface before too many episodes have elapsed.

Comment: Totally forgot to check the dates.  Gurren Lagaan came out in 2007, so it doesn't match the time period you said.

Answer (score 1):

Birth or The world of the Talisman (1984). I also had it on VHS when I was a kid an watched it a hundred times. I was searching for it for quite a while as well. Hope you enjoy revisiting it!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain the specific ways in which it matches the anime described in the question.

Comment: Potentially matching scene at minute 52: underground city, boy on bike and girl on one-wheele vehicle escaping from two giant robots (a red one and a blue one).